# Cannot get PHP to serve on Nginx -- Error 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, nginx

I'm fairly new to nginx and assumed it would be very straightforward to serve php with it since that setup is so common, but it seems like it's much more complex than I anticipated.

Here's my config..

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

            location / {
                    root   /srv/www/domain.com/public_html;
                    index index.php;
            }

    # serve static files directly
    #location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)$
    #    access_log        off;
    #    expires           30d;

            location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
                    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                            return 404;
                    }

                    fastcgi_pass /var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
            }
    }
```

If I replace the "index.php" with a "index.html" file, nginx serves up the html perfectly. But switching over to php causes a 502 error.

I've seen guides that recommend modifying anything from iptables to php-fpm to the php.ini, to fast-cgi to sites-available..?

I'm not sure what many of these tutorials are trying to do exactly... for now I'd just like my index.php to serve up phpinfo(). What's the next step?

Is there a clear guide that goes over the various options available for serving php with nginx?

Comment: Debian wheezy 7.3 on xen

Comment: Should I modify them? If so, what changes should I make and for what purpose exactly? This seems like it should be part of a longer answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install php-fpm and add this section: http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample

Comment: What does php-fpm do?

Comment: php-fpm proccess the php file. Well, you call from browse URL e.g. http:url.com/index.php, this call takes nginx a send it to php-fpm. php-fpm proccess it and return answer to nginx and nginx to your browser.

Comment: thank you, that's helpful.  I made the changes suggested here: wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample as well as Rahil's change to the php.ini, restarted everything, now it is giving a 403 forbidden instead of the 502 error..

Comment: Make sure you have index.php in index statement (as above), and index.php is in good section. Try change fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; to fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; and restart nginx

Comment: Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:67

Comment: Try edit /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and find section listen and uncomment socket.

Comment: Great call, it was already uncommented though.  I updated my config above in case you see anything else wrong with it.  Is it wrong to have two location blocks like that? Should I merge them somehow?

Comment: You can have multiple locations, just add into your code { and } like in php example.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have successfully installed [php-fpm (FastCGI Process Manager)](http://php-fpm.org/download/)

Go to `php-fpm/php.ini`

Find the line `cgi.fix_pathinfo=1`, uncomment it and change the value `1` to `0`.

`cgi.fix_pathinfo=0`

Now restart `php-fpm` service.

Through your terminal

`service php5-fpm restart` (I'm not sure about your Linux distro must be same)

Comment: well, I made the changes suggested here: http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample as well as your change to the php.ini, restarted everything, now it is giving a 403 forbidden instead of the 502, so I guess that's progress.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue with the permission, you can identify the error in the log file

- Extract the record from the log

  022/08/09 20:37:27 [crit] 3930#0: *17 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.80.36, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1"

This give clue that server conflict, now to verify which user running we need to check the php-fpm and nginx worker node

- **Worker Node**
  Execute the command
  `ps aux | grep 'nginx'`
  this will indicate the user of the nginx worker node, in this case it is **nobody**

  root@ubuntu:/var/nginx/html# ps aux | grep 'nginx'
- **nobody**    3930  0.0  0.0  37636  3784 ?        S    20:37   0:00 nginx: worker process
- *Check the php fpm service*
  Execute the command
  `ps aux | grep 'php-fpm'`
  It will indicate the user as "www-data" in my case

  root@ubuntu:/var/nginx/html# ps aux | grep 'php'
- **www-data**  1320  0.0  0.2 498796 11908 ?        S    19:34   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
- www-data  1323  0.0  0.2 498796 11908 ?        S    19:34   0:00 php-fpm: pool www

To resolve this conflict, in the nginx.conf file, you have to define the user derivate at top to be www-data i.e. **user www-data;**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).